# rails 3, How to set and pass a query string through an Controller#create action that doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, query-string

I have 3 views that the users sees in an order, first they select a location, next then select a category, then they get sent to a form.  The first view sends the location info to the category select view.  From the category select view, I am using a query string to send the category id through to a form.   In the Controller#new action I am putting the query string into an instance variable: @award = Award.find(params[:award])

the issue is that if the user does not fill in the appropriate fields, then the form doesn't save, and the query string no longer exists.  Which in my case means that a recommendation doesn't have a category anymore which will then continue to make the form fail.

How can I persist the query string through a failed create action?

```
def create
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new(params[:recommendation])
    @recommendation.user_id = current_user.id


    respond_to do |format|
      if @recommendation.save
        format.html { redirect_to location_path, notice: 'Recommendation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @recommendation, status: :created, location: @recommendation }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @recommendation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

EDIT *_*

I figured I could share the new action to:

```
def new
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new
    @award = Award.find(params[:award])
    @recommendation.approvals.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @recommendation }
    end
  end
```

Comment: you can always 'persist' data in a hidden field on the form

Comment: I the view contains a hidden field but the hidden field is populated by the instance varaible which returns nill after failure to save.

Comment: @TJ Sherrill I'm assuming you have the recommendation object populating the form and a hidden field on that form corresponding to recommendation.category (and you've set its value when you initially render the form).  If submitting that form and fails, you want your controller action to re-render that form with the recommendation object's data; in which you have stored that category value.  This isn't happening? If you don't have category as an attribute on the recommendation object - be sure to add it via attr_accessor or as a db column through a migration.

Comment: Awards and Categories are a HABTM so both have many of each other so I can't simply add an attr_accessor, right?

Answer (score 0):

well, since the querystring is already being passed from the new action to the create action, if the create action fails, it will hit your 'format.html { render action: "new" }' line.

you could do something like this:

```
format.html {redirect_to thing_path(@thing, :foo => params[:foo])}
```

Comment: I would have to provide redirect_to new_recommendation_path(:award => @award) which returns that it cant find an award...